# How to select text and change selected color using mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function getSelectedText() {
  var selectedText = '';
  if (window.getSelection) {
    selectedText = window.getSelection();
  } else if (document.getSelection) {
    selectedText = document.getSelection();
  } else if (document.selection) {
    selectedText =
      document.selection.createRange().text;
  } else return;
  document.testform.selectedtext.value = selectedText;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Selected Text</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p>
    <b>Why do we use it?</b>
    <br/> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
    here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various
    versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
  </p>
  <input type="button" value="Get Selection" onmousedown="getSelectedText()">
  <form name="testform">
    <textarea name="selectedtext" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

In this code I have select text through mouse but only when I click on `get selection` button. I want to select text through mouse and change background color of selected text and it will show still selected. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: check [document.execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)  and [example](https://codepen.io/chrisdavidmills/full/gzYjag/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mouseup` and `mousedown` to simulate `drag` text, also wrap your selected text with a span to change color.

```js
function getSelectedText() {
  var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
  var span = $("<span class='selected'>" + selectedText.textContent + "</span>");
  selection.insertNode(span[0]);

  if (selection) {
    $('textarea').text(selection)
  }

}

$('p').mouseup(function() {
  getSelectedText()
});

$('p').mousedown(function() {
  $(this).find('.selected').contents().unwrap();;
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<p>
  <b>Why do we use it?</b>
  <br/> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
  here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various
  versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</p>
<form name="testform">
  <textarea name="selectedtext" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
</form>
```

**Edit:** Improved jQuery version replaced

Answer (score 1):

We have Document Web API to control entire document editable by turning on and off.
document.designMode = "on" || "off"

After document gets editable you need to execute command for changing font color

Ref for other commands: https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Commands

document.execCommand("ForeColor", false, "red");

You can use on mouse event to execute your function.

```js
function getSelectedText() { 
            var selectedText = '';
            if (window.getSelection) { 
                selectedText = window.getSelection(); 
            }
            else if (document.getSelection) { 
                selectedText = document.getSelection(); 
            }  
            else if (document.selection) { 
                selectedText = 
                document.selection.createRange().text; 
            } 
            else return;
            document.testform.selectedtext.value = selectedText; 
   
     document.designMode = "on";
     document.execCommand("ForeColor", false, "red");
     document.designMode = "off";
        }
```

```html
<p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>Why do we use it?</b>
        <br/>
        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    </p>
    <input type="button" value="Get Selection" onmousedown="getSelectedText(event)">
    <form name="testform"> 
        <textarea name="selectedtext" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea> 
    </form>
```